# Applying GZIP for a website under IIS?

Tags: gzip

How to find out whether particular web server's GZip  is enabled or not and How to apply the 
GZip compression for the  web site under IIS 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS GUI doesn't support turning compression on in IIS6. You'll need to update the IIS metabase directly with the settings instead.

The MSDN documentation gives [a high level overview](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true) of HTTP compression but doesn't talk about getting the changes into the metabase. I found some [instructions](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/12/57916.aspx) and a helpful [metabase example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html).